# Disable windows file caching

Tags: windows, winapi, caching

The Task Manager of Windows 7 lists, in the performance tab, the number of megabytes of physical memory used as a cache.

I want to measure the performance of my program under the assumption that the disked-based data (a 700 MB file) cannot be stored in main memory. In reality I have plenty of RAM. Can I somehow enforce the file to be read from disk?

I've already tried disabling EnablePrefetcher and EnableSuperfetcher in the register, but nothing changed. A hack that works is allocating all the available memory. Would a combination of FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING and FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED provide the desired result? Any other ideas?

*BTW: I conclude the file is read from cache because the first time I start the application it runs substantially slower than subsequent runs. If I allocate all available memory, the next run is slow again. Also, I see the cache growing quickly in the Task Manager the first time the application is run.*

*Off topic:

The irony is that we are implementing an algorithm that assumes you cannot store the file in main memory. However, we cannot **not** store it in main memory... :)*

Comment: FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING does indeed read like it would do what you want.

Comment: It does, even though I'm not a 100% sure from the MSDN documentation. However, it "requires special application considerations", which don't sound easy. If there is no easy fix I will figure out if/how I can meet these [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Mathijs: Either allocating most of the memory or `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` should work. The requirements for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` are not that hard. Don't seek to a position in the file that is not a multiple of `512` and never specify a `NumberOfBytesToRead` for `ReadFile()` that's not a multiple of `512`.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?